# Bean not found error while using Reactive Mongo with Webflux

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I am doing a sample application and trying to use webflux with reactive mongo.
I am getting below error while starting the application in Intellij

```
required a bean of type 'com.sample.ReservationRepositroy' that could not be found.
```

I am having below entries in the gradle

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.1'
```

Repository Code as below

```
interface ReservationRepositroy extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Reservation,String>{}

@Autowired
    private final ReservationRepositroy reservationRepositroy;

@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Reservation {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

I tried adding @Repository in the repository class as well as @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories in SpringBoot application but same error. Also tried extending ReactiveCrudRepository.
Anything I am missing?

Comment: Can you share the full application on GitHub?

Comment: It worked when I moved the content to seperate public classes @MartinTarjányi Thank You

Comment: I had the same issue. I added repository package to @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories("com.yourpackage.repository") to let spring scan the repositories. hope this workaround helps you.